# Python fuzzy string search with `regex`

Tags: python, regex, fuzzy-search

Trying to understand fuzzy pattern matching with [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).  What I want: I have a string, and I want to find identical or similar strings in other, perhaps larger strings. (Does one field in a database record occur, perhaps as a fuzzy substring, in any other field in that database record?)

Here's a sample. Comments indicate character positions.

```
import regex
to_search = "1990 /"
            #123456
            # ^^ ^
search_in = "V CAD-0000:0000[01] ISS 23/10/91"
            #12345678901234567890123456789012
            #                           ^^ ^
m = regex.search(f'({to_search}){{e<4}}', search_in, regex.BESTMATCH)
```

result:

```
>>> m
<regex.Match object; span=(27, 30), match='10/', fuzzy_counts=(0, 0, 3)>
>>> m.fuzzy_changes
([], [], [28, 29, 31])
```

No substitutions, no insertions, 3 deletions at positions 28, 29 and 31. The order "substitutions insertions deletions" matters, it's taken from [here](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).

Question: how to interpret this, in normal human language? What it *says* (I think):

> "You have a match from substring `10/` in your `search_in`, if you delete positions 28, 29 and 31 in it."

I probably got that wrong. This is true tho':

> "If you delete positions 5, 3 and 2, in that order, in `to_search`, you have an exact match at substring `10/` in `search_in`, yay!"

Fortunately, I found [a guru!](https://maxhalford.github.io/blog/fuzzy-regex-matching-in-python/) So I did

```
>>> import orc
>>> m = regex.search(f'({to_search}){{e<4}}', search_in, regex.BESTMATCH)
>>> m
<regex.Match object; span=(27, 30), match='10/', fuzzy_counts=(0, 0, 3)>
>>> near_match = orc.NearMatch.from_regex(m, to_search)
>>> print(near_match)
10/
 I
190/
  I
1990/
    I
1990 /
```

Hmm... so the order of `fuzzy_counts`, is in fact, something, something, *insertions*?

I'd appreciate if anyone could shed some light on this.

Comment: Nobody understands Python's _fuzzy_ i,d,s,e. The regex source code that tries this has to be primitive to be performative and is really only applicable on the language 'word' level. The whole notion is kinda fuzzy.

Comment: @sin How reassuring. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are close. but according to the docs you mentioned in the post, this is what is going on here.

```
import regex
to_search = "1990 /"
            #123456
            # ^^ ^
search_in = "V CAD-0000:0000[01] ISS 23/10/91"
            #12345678901234567890123456789012
            #                           ^^ ^
m = regex.search(f'({to_search}){{e<4}}', search_in, regex.BESTMATCH)
m
```

output:

```
<regex.Match object; span=(27, 30), match='10/', fuzzy_counts=(0, 0, 3)>
```

```
m.fuzzy_changes
```

output:

```
([], [], [28, 29, 31])
```

---

### EXPLAINATION

let's break it down step by step:

#### The Context:

You're searching for the exact sequence "1990 /" within a longer text "V CAD-0000:0000[01] ISS 23/10/91".

#### The Findings:

- **Match Found**: search discovered a similar sequence "10/" within the longer text.
- **Position**: This "10/" sequence was found starting at positions 27 to 30 in the longer text.

#### The Analysis:

To get an exact match we should have had the longer string as this

`V CAD-0000:0000[01] ISS 23/1990 /91`

However, there were a few changes made to that string to get the actual string.

#### Changes:

1. **Deletions**:

   - **Locations**: Positions 28, 29, and 31 in the presumed original sequence `V CAD-0000:0000[01] ISS 23/1990 /91` were deleted.
   - **Resultant String**: After these deletions, the presumed original sequence became the actual sequence `V CAD-0000:0000[01] ISS 23/10/91`.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation. I now understand the result better, but I'm still mystified as to why it starts out with "To get an exact match we should have had the longer string as X". One would expect the edit distance from `to_search` to a substring in `search_in`. One gets the edit distance from a hypothetical substring in `search_in` matching `to_search`, to `search_in`. I can see it boils down to the same thing. I'm just intrigued by the approach.